# Searching for Schema:table static method definition in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I'm trying to understand PHP Laravel Framework. Whend dealing with databases, we use Schema::table to create a table in the database. Searching in my application I find the only definition is

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder
 */
class Schema extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get a schema builder instance for a connection.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder
     */
    public static function connection($name)
    {
        return static::$app['db']->connection($name)->getSchemaBuilder();
    }

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return static::$app['db']->connection()->getSchemaBuilder();
    }

}
```

but there is not a `table` static method neither in `Schema` class or in `Facade` class.

What piece I'm missing?

Comment: You need to understand laravel IOC and facades. Read about laravel Facades on laravel documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Schema` here is only facade. Method `table()` and other methods from `Schema` can be found in file: `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php` .

Other methods can be found in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint.php`

You should always look at [Facade Class Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades#facade-class-reference) to know what class you are really using.